# Poetry add always takes 5 minutes to resolve dependencies

Tags: python, python-poetry

I have a fairly large project, and everytime I want to install a dependency it takes like 5 minutes on an M1 MacBook pro. Can someone please help me with my constraints, and debugging where the dependency resolver is spending time?

*pyproject.toml*

```ini
[tool.poetry.dependencies]
python = "^3.10"
streamlit = "^1.15.2"
openai = "0.27.0"
python-decouple = "^3.6"
requests = "^2.28.1"
glom = "^22.1.0"
parse = "^1.19.0"
html2text = "^2020.1.16"
pandas = "^2.0.1"
google-cloud-firestore = "^2.7.0"
replicate = "^0.4.0"
fastapi = "^0.85.0"
uvicorn = {extras = ["standard"], version = "^0.18.3"}
firebase-admin = "^6.0.0"
# mediapipe for M1 macs
mediapipe-silicon = {version = "^0.8.11", markers = "platform_machine == 'arm64'", platform = "darwin"}
# mediapipe for others
mediapipe = {version = "^0.8.11", markers = "platform_machine != 'arm64'"}
furl = "^2.1.3"
itsdangerous = "^2.1.2"
pytest = "^7.2.0"
google-cloud-texttospeech = "^2.12.1"
Wand = "^0.6.10"
readability-lxml = "^0.8.1"
transformers = "^4.24.0"
stripe = "^5.0.0"
python-multipart = "^0.0.5"
html-sanitizer = "^1.9.3"
plotly = "^5.11.0"
sentry-sdk = "^1.12.0"
httpx = "^0.23.1"
pyquery = "^1.4.3"
redis = "^4.5.1"
pytest-xdist = "^3.2.0"
requests-html = "^0.10.0"
pdftotext = "^2.2.2"
"pdfminer.six" = "^20221105"
google-api-python-client = "^2.80.0"
oauth2client = "^4.1.3"
tiktoken = "^0.3.2"
google-cloud-translate = ">=2.0.1,<2.1.0"
google-cloud-speech = "^2.21.0"
yt-dlp = "^2023.3.4"
llama-index = "^0.5.27"
nltk = "^3.8.1"
Jinja2 = "^3.1.2"
Django = "^4.2"
django-phonenumber-field = {extras = ["phonenumberslite"], version = "^7.0.2"}
gunicorn = "^20.1.0"
psycopg2-binary = "^2.9.6"
whitenoise = "^6.4.0"
black = "^23.3.0"
django-extensions = "^3.2.1"
pytest-django = "^4.5.2"
celery = "^5.3.1"
qrcode = "^7.4.2"
opencv-contrib-python = "^4.7.0.72"
numpy = "^1.25.0"
pyzbar = "^0.1.9"
gspread = "^5.10.0"
hashids = "^1.3.1"
langcodes = "^3.3.0"
language-data = "^1.1"
simplejson = "^3.19.1"

[tool.poetry.group.dev.dependencies]
watchdog = "^2.1.9"
ipython = "^8.5.0"

[build-system]
requires = ["poetry-core"]
build-backend = "poetry.core.masonry.api"
```

```
$ poetry --version
Poetry (version 1.5.1)
$ python --version
Python 3.10.5
```

```
$ poetry add google-cloud-documentai
Using version ^2.18.0 for google-cloud-documentai

Updating dependencies
Resolving dependencies... (344.7s)

Package operations: 1 install, 9 updates, 0 removals

  • Updating certifi (2022.12.7 -> 2023.5.7)
  • Updating charset-normalizer (2.0.12 -> 3.2.0)
  • Updating packaging (21.3 -> 23.1)
  • Updating urllib3 (1.26.13 -> 1.26.16)
  • Updating requests (2.27.1 -> 2.31.0)
  • Updating cryptography (3.4.6 -> 41.0.2)
  • Updating pygments (2.14.0 -> 2.15.1)
  • Updating pyyaml (6.0 -> 6.0.1)
  • Updating pyjwt (2.4.0 -> 2.8.0)
  • Installing google-cloud-documentai (2.18.0)

Writing lock file
```

Comment: What version of poetry are you using? I believe dependency resolver has been changing quite a bit between recent releases

Comment: Poetry (version 1.5.1)

Comment: Would be worth [edit]ing that into the question so that people can rule out old version issues.

Comment: Just as a general observation, at least some of those dependencies have fairly old lower bounds (e.g. `fastapi = "^0.85.0"` is ~1 year old, latest is v0.100.1). That is likely making graph of version candidates very big. Tightening those bounds may help.

Comment: As far as debugging where the dependency resolver is spending time, you could try profiling poetry using any Python profiler. Find your poetry installation's venv (e.g. `head $(which poetry)`), then run something like `<poetry venv>/bin/python -m cProfile -s cumtime -m poetry add ...`